# How to prevent form from submitting Ajax onBegin

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following:

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.requiredif.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnFailure = "PartError", OnBegin="return Test();" , OnSuccess = "PartSuccess" }, new { id = "partForm" }))
```

{

}

```
 function Test() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("TestJs", "Home")",
        data: { },
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
            return false;
    }
});
}
```

Even though, I returned false, the form keeps on submitting.  What do I do wrong.  Please help!  Thank you!

Comment: you are not returning anything from function `Test()`. A return inside `success` does nothing and certainly doesn't return to the outer function

Comment: Can you give me an example?  thanks.

Comment: you basically need an if statement to even run the ajax call.  Read it literally, "Send an ajax request with all of the information. on success, return false".  That's what you have written there